# Extract dataframes from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'col1': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'], 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
dic = {}
for frame, data in df.groupby('col1'):
   dic[f'df_{frame}'] = data
```

The above should create a dictionary of 3 dataframes. I would just like those 3 dataframes extracted and having some trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "extracted"? After running the code, does `dic` appear to have the value you want it to have? If so, what actually is the problem? Why doesn't that count as "having those dataframes extracted"?

Comment: i.e not in a dictionary format. Basically like unnesting. So if I wanted to call the dataframe... instead of d['df_a'].. I just want df_a. So can I loop through the dictionary and create a dataframe for each key?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very good practice, but it will work. Use `globals()` instead of `dic`:

```py
d = {'col1': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'], 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
for frame, data in df.groupby('col1'):
   globals()[f'df_{frame}'] = data
```

Output:

```
>>> df_a
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    a     2

>>> df_b
  col1  col2
2    b     3
3    b     4

>>> df_c
  col1  col2
4    c     5
5    c     6
```

Comment: I can see how this can 'break'. If I had spaces in my first col values for example 'a b' then the resulting df would be df_a b and wouldn't be able to call that. Maybe replace spaces with '_' in col_1 to fix this. Any other reason why this could be considered 'not very good practice'?